# View не видит переменную из контроллера (laravel, php)

Tags: php, laravel, controller, blade

Есть одностраничный сайт, создаю админку к нему на фреймворке Laravel.

Модель и меню админики сгенерировано по данному гайду http://laravel.su/articles/laravel-sleeping-owl-crud-for-dummers, записи в БД сохраняет, перезаписывает и удаляет. Но не получается вывести данное редактирование в HTML.

А так же нужны ли роуты для одностраничного сайта? Заранее благодарен

Модель:

```
class supplier extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'supplier';
    protected $fillable = [
        'url', 'image_sup',
    ];
}
```

Контроллер:

```
use App\supplier;    

class supplierController extends Controller  {
     public function execute (){
         $image_sup = supplier::all();   $url= supplier::all();
         return view('welcome', ['image_sup'=>$image_sup,],['url'=>$url]);
     }
}
```

Роут:

```
Route::get('/', 'supplierController@execute');
```

HTML код:

```
    @if (isset($image_sup) && is_object($image_sup) && (isset($url)) && is_object($url))

    @foreach($image_sup as $image)
        @foreach($url as $urls)
    <div class="mbr-cards-col col-xs-12 col-lg-4" style="padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 80px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card cart-block">
                <div class="card-img">

                    <a href = "{{$urls}}" target="blank"> <img src=" {{$image}}  " class="card-img-top"> </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            @endforeach
 @endforeach
        @endif
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

проблема в конфликтующих маршрутах в файле роута

Answer (score 0):

$image_sup = supplier::all();
$url= supplier::all(); 
Получается, что $url - коллекция объектов и $image_sup тоже коллекция тех же объектов. $image и $urls это объекты модели supplier, не поля таблицы, поэтому ничего и не выводит.
Надо вот так:
в контроллере $suppliers = supplier::all();
во вьюхе:

```
@foreach($suppliers as $supplier)

<div class="mbr-cards-col col-xs-12 col-lg-4" style="padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 80px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card cart-block">
            <div class="card-img">

                <a href = "{{$supplier->url}}" target="blank"> <img src=" {{$supplier->image_sup}}  " class="card-img-top"> </a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: `public function execute ()
    {
      
         return view('welcome',$suppliers = supplier::all());
     }`
делал по вашему примеру, но
мой контроллер выглядит вот так, к сожалению ошибка все еще присутствует Undefined variable: suppliers

Comment: public function execute () { return view('welcome', ['suppliers' => supplier::all())] }

Comment: во вьюху 'welcome' мы должны передать переменные в массиве, в данном случае во вьюхе переменная $suppliers будет нам доступна, если мы передадим ее в ключе массива, а значение соответственно в значении

Comment: `return view('welcome',['suppliers' => supplier::all()]);`
у вас немного неправильно поставлены скобки, но в целом работает всс

Comment: если мы хотим использовать несколько переменных, то почему то снова появляется ошибка видимости переменных, я считаю что это проблема в маршруте, так ли это ?

Comment: нет, добавляем в массив еще одну и все, ['suppliers' => supplier::all(), 'some_var' => $some_var]

Comment: если мы будем делать другой контроллер и выбирать так же все поля из таблицы ?

Comment: можно не все поля выбирать, а только нужные, можно пагинацию сделать